# Amazon S3 file upload via torrent

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I know that amazon-S3 supports  BitTorrent and that we can download files using a torrent client. My question is,

Is it possible to upload files from my pc to s3 via torrent, either directly or using ec2 ?

**Note:**
I have a website where users upload large size video files which are stored in S3. It would be helpful if they could just upload a torrent file so that they can seed whenever they want and also have multiple seeders for the same file which decreases their upload time...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to install a BitTorrent client on EC2 (or on your own system), download the torrent file, and upload it to S3. S3 does not natively support fetching BitTorrent files from other sources and storing them in a bucket.

Answer (score -5):

you can set a PUBLIC s3 file as downloadable by torrent if you add ?torrent at the end of the url.

For example, I just now uploaded following file:

`http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/Install/hexagon4.png`

if you set the link to

`http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/Install/hexagon4.png?torrent`

it will be downloaded as torrent.

I don't know if this is possible to do for closed files

Comment: Thanks... But I want to upload to S3 using a torrent client and not download from it. Is this possible ?

Comment: ah. in this case the other answer provides the best option